# A cascade of inequalities

Tags: inequality

Given the following set of equations, show that all the variables (for any length list) must each be $\ge 0$.

$$ 2x_1 -x_2 \ge 0 $$
$$ -x_1 + 2x_2 -x_3 \ge 0 $$
$$ -x_2 + 2x_3 -x_4 \ge 0 $$
$$ -x_3 + 2x_4 -x_5 \ge 0 $$
$$...$$
$$ -x_{n-2} + 2x_{n-1} -x_n \ge 0 $$
$$ -x_{n-1} + 2x_n\ge 0 $$

I know if I add them all up I get $x_1 + x_n \ge 0$ but I don't know if $x_n \ge 0$. If I did then I could plug in to each equation moving up to get them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the short case:
$$\begin{array}{lc}2a-b\ge 0& (1)\\ -a+2b-c\ge 0 &(2)\\ -b+2c-d\ge 0 &(3) \\ -c =  2d \ge 0 &(4) \end{array}$$

$(1) + 2(2)$ gives
$$3b-2c\ge 0\hspace{.25in} (5)$$

And $(5)+3(3)$ gives
$$4c-3d\ge 0\hspace{.25in} (6)$$

And  $(6)+4(4)$ gives
$$5d\ge 0$$

Which shows that your last variable is greater than or equal to $0$.  And along with your observation $a+$(last variable)$\ge 0$, you said that would be enough for you to finish off the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_{k^*}$ be the largest of the $x_k$. From the inequalities
$$x_2-x_1\geq x_3-x_2\geq x_4-x_3\geq\ldots\geq x_{k^*}-x_{k^*-1}\geq0$$
and
$$x_n-x_{n-1}\leq x_{n-1}- x_{n-2}\leq\ldots\leq x_{k^*+1}-x_{k^*}\leq0$$
it follows that the sequence $k\mapsto x_k$ is (weakly) increasing for $k\leq k^*$ and (weakly) decreasing for $k\geq k^*$. Therefore the smallest $x_k$ is one (or both) of $x_1$, $x_n$. In any case your first inequality gives $x_1\geq x_2-x_1\geq0$, and  your last inequality gives $x_n\geq x_{n-1}-x_n\geq0$.